# Android, Logging Sensor Data to a File

Tags: android, logging, android-sensors

I would like to log sensor data (Accelerometer, Gyro, Magnetometer, GPS, etc.) and record a time history which can be accessed for future plotting and analysis (as well as some real time calculations).  I am a MATLAB programmer, so .csv files came to mind, but I've also seen a little about MySql, which I'm not too familiar with.

My question is, which datalogging method is most appropriate?  I'm not limited to the two mentioned above, they're simply what I've seen so far.  Any suggestions/ example codes?

PS, I've also run across MicroLog4Android (http://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/) but there are not any examples which I have come across, and being new to Android, I cannot tell if its meant for logging higher speed data (10-20 Hz) or if it's simply a program errorlog.  It has some cool features (SMS sending, network storage, etc.) which make it attractive if this is indeed an appropriate tool.

Comment: Since you mention logging personally sensitive data such as location, you should be very aware of where and how you log this and be sure that you fully disclose to the user what you are doing. For example, the SD card or "external" storage on Android is treated as a shared resource - any app can read any file on a device's SD card. You do not want to store personally sensitive data in a place where it can be accessed by other apps.

Comment: adamp, thanks for the consideration, I will certainly let the users know.  This is intended to be a datalogging application, so if the user selects to use GPS they will know that this data is stored.  I'm not sure why storing a GPS track of something, say a ski route, would be of any use to any other apps, but I guess this is up to the end user if they are concerned. Any suggestions on the implementation format?